# Mongoose error: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "null" (type string) at path "_id" for model ... "

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently creating simple CRUD app that lets me create products and store it in a Mongo database. The app is working fine, except that it is constantly throwing an error message when I try to go to my '/products/show' page (or when working with a specific product).

I don't really know what is happening as this is my first time working with Mongoose and MongoDB. The app is working fine, which it should, but this error message is causing the program to continue loading even when everything is on the screen.

### My index.js file

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Product = require('./models/product');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/farmStand', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("MONGO CONNECTION IS OPEN!");
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Oh no.. Mongo error");
        console.log(err);
    });

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Product.find({});
    res.render('products/index', { products });
});

app.get('/products/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('products/new');
});

app.post('/products', async (req, res) => {
    const newProduct = new Product(req.body);
    await newProduct.save();
    console.log(newProduct);
    res.redirect(`/products/${newProduct._id}`);
});

// This is where the error is occuring.
app.get('/products/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
        res.render('products/show', { product });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("APP IS LISTENING ON PORT 3000");
});
```

### My productSchema file

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        enum: ['fruit', 'vegetables', "dairy"]
    }
});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

### My EJS '/show' file

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title><%= product.name %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><%= product.name %></h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Price: $<%= product.price %></li>
            <li>Category: <%= product.category %></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="/products">All products</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

### The error message

```bash
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "null" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"
    at ObjectId.cast (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:250:11)
    at SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1220:12)
    at SchemaType.castForQuery (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1632:15)
    at cast (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:356:32)
    at Query.cast (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4910:12)
    at Query._castConditions (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2232:10)
    at model.Query._findOne (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2519:8)
    at model.Query.exec (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4429:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/index.js:40:25 {
  stringValue: '"null"',
  messageFormat: undefined,
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'null',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
      at new ObjectId (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson.cjs:2006:23)
      at castObjectId (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast/objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:248:12)
      at SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1220:12)
      at SchemaType.castForQuery (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1632:15)
      at cast (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:356:32)
      at Query.cast (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4910:12)
      at Query._castConditions (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2232:10)
      at model.Query._findOne (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2519:8)
      at model.Query.exec (/Users/nielskoop/Coding/UdemyCourse/MongoDB/38_mongoose-express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4429:28),
  valueType: 'string',
  model: Model { Product }
}
```

### Solutions I have tried

I could not really find much information on this subject online, and the information that was available was quite confusing. I've tried adding an `if` statement to check whether the given id `isValid`, but that just stops the program from working altogether. I also tried to convert the ID given by Mongoose into a simple string and store it in a separate variable so that I could work with it later, but that also stopped the program from working altogether.

### Desired solution

I would like to find out what is causing this error and how to fix it. I have the feeling that when I go to the '/show' page the code continues running and checking for a new ID value in Mongoose, which is not there. I might be completely wrong, however.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that I was very close with my solution by putting the `findByID()` call in an `if` statement. This is my code now:

```js
app.get('/products/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
            const product = await Product.findById(id);
            res.render('products/show', { product });
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

It does not throw the error message anymore. My question now is if this code is good like this, or if it can be improved in some way? Also, the page continues loading until eternity, and that is a thorn in my eye. Is that normal behavior, or is that not good? If it's not good, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely **don't** need to run an `if (id.match...){...}` statement to make your `findById(id)` work.

The error message tells you that:

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "null" (type string) at path "_id"
```

So in this code:

```
app.post('/products', async (req, res) => {
   const newProduct = new Product(req.body);
   await newProduct.save();
   console.log(newProduct);
   res.redirect(`/products/${newProduct._id}`); //< You are sending null
});
```

I suspect than on some occasions something is not quite right with your `const newProduct` and mongoose is not creating the Product, which then has a knock on effect when you try to redirect. You think you are redirecting to:

```
res.redirect(`/products/${newProduct._id}`);
//            /products/64f7728ac8718d458e441283
```

but in actual fact you are redirecting to:

```
res.redirect(`/products/${newProduct._id}`);
//            /products/null
```

So `req.params.id` is `null` in your:

```
app.get('/products/:id', async (req, res) => {
   try {
      const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id); //< req.params.id = null
   }
   //...
   //...
});
```

You need a `try/catch` block in your `app.post('/products'...)` to find out when the creation of a product is failing. At the minute you just blindly redirect. Implement this change:

```
app.post('/products', async (req, res, next) => {
   try{
      const newProduct = new Product(req.body);
      await newProduct.save();
      console.log(newProduct);
      res.redirect(`/products/${newProduct._id}`);
   } catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
   }
});
```

Your code looks pretty good otherwise and it's maybe just an issue with the data you are actually posting that is causing the Product not to create.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have implemented your code, and I continue to have the issue shown in my post. Chrome keeps loading and I get the error message that was thrown without the `if` statement.

Comment: If chrome keep loading then the error or promise isn't being dealt with. Change the `next(err)` in my solution to `res.status(400).json({ error : err });` and you will see what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that `req.params.id` is returning the correct id, because it does go to the correct page, and immediately after `req.params.id` returns a null value which crashes the program.

Comment: This is definitely unusual behaviour. What does `console.log('id', req.params.id)` output if you put it as the first statement in your `app.get('/products/:id` route?

Comment: `id 64f763ae585b41f59f85c7c5`
`id null`

This is the output I get when I do that.

Comment: Just stopped and started the server and I still have the same issue. I don't have 2 `app.get` routes for the same route, and I don't believe that I have multiple instances of the server running. Is there a way for me to check how many instances of the server are running? I am using Nodemon by the way.

Comment: Nodemon will throw an error if trying to listen on the same port as one already being lsitened on, my apologies. The only thing I can think of is your application may be making the same request twice to `/products/${newProduct._id}` but on the second occasion the `${newProduct._id}` is null. How are you sending data to your `app.post` . Is it using fetch, axios etc?